# Google appEngine: 404 when accessing /_ah/api

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I try to build a very simple GAE application, using eclipse and the Google Plugin for Eclipse.
I've generated some Endpoint from an @Entity class, then I've generated Cloud Endpoint Client library.

After that I've started the appEngine project (within eclipse, on the embedded jetty server). When I try to access /_ah/api I get the following issue:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/api/. Reason:

Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404

Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:102)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:67)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:117)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
```

Comment: Update: it seems to happen, when I set a --address=192.168.0.101 param when starting the webapp. Without this parameter I do not get the error above (but localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer/ does not show anything)

Comment: same here, I can't leave localhost since I want to debug on real device

Answer (score 3):

I was able to test in real device by setting `--address=0.0.0.0` in run configuration.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400196