# Does Objectify 4.0 work with Endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have tried to switch my fledgling project from [Objectify 3.1](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify) to [Objectify 4.0](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Introduction).  It compiles but if I try to go to the API browser (), it fails with a 500 error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/api/explorer. Reason:

Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:102)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:67)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:117)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My suspicion is that this has to do with JDO being disabled in accordance with the instructions on [upgrading from v3 to v4](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/UpgradeVersion3ToVersion4) which say:

> Completely remove JDO & JPA
>
> Objectify v4 no longer uses any JPA
> annotations. However, several of the new annotations have identical
> names but different packages (eg, javax.persistence.Entity ->
> com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity). By removing the JPA
> annotations from your classpath, your IDE will highlight all the (now
> invalid) references to old annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...  It seems like that turning off JDO is only for *finding* every place you need to change but once it's all compiling again you have to **turn it back on**.

This can actually be a bit challenging under Windows because it tries to adjust libraries that are open (and Windows cannot delete a file that is open).  I had to read the Error Log, find out what file it was unable to delete, and then quickly delete that file manually while Eclipse was restarting.  Then turn JDO on and hope for no more conflicts.

After that, it worked!  (Or, at least, I advanced to the next problem...  )

Answer (score 0):

Objectify 4.0 works with endpoints, that's I'm sure of.

Are you testing on real device? I just solved the same problem: [Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404 - Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031426/failed-to-retrieve-api-configs-with-status-404-google-app-engine)