# Debugging Google Web Application projects with Google Cloud Endpoints in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-endpoints

My iOS app uses a Java-based server and communicates with it using Google Cloud Endpoints. Normally the server listens on `https://myservice.appspot.com/_ah/api/rpc`.

How can I debug my server code? After I run it with *Debug As* | *Web Application* inside Eclipse and change its URL to `https://localhost:8888/_ah/api/rpc` the client cannot connect. I don't think it's a firewall issue because URLs with `localhost:8888` work for other client-server pairs.

So does one need to take any special steps for debugging code in Google Web Application projects with Google Cloud Endpoints in Eclipse, and is there a better way to set their required URL on the client than hardcoding it (like I currently try)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first cause why this did not work was that I tried to connect to `localhost` over SSL.

The second cause was that my real device of course needs to contact the dev server not as `localhost`, but using its remote IP address (currently `10.0.0.2` on my WLAN).

The third cause was that the firewall on my OS X 10.9.3 Mac prevented my real device from connecting to its port 8888. I had to disable *Block all incoming connections* and allow incoming connections for the applications *Eclipse* and *java* under *System Preferences* | *Security & Privacy* | *Firewall Options*. (OS X will prompt for permission the first time a connection is attempted.)