# Google Cloud Endpoint local testing exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

While testing a Google cloud endpoint API using JS it always returned null. While investigating, I opened the API root URL in a new tab **`http://localhost:8888/_ah/api`**
and the below exception was thrown:

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/api. Reason:

```
String index out of range: 0
```

Caused by:

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.DevApiUtil.stripLeadingSlash(DevApiUtil.java:17)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you hit /_ah/api/explorer endpoint ? do you see the list of APIs listed and are you able to invoke/test the APIs via the API Explorer?

Comment: @Romin yes, That's why it's weird!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console just prior to invoking any API ? Have the Google client libraries loaded properly ?

Comment: @Romin Yes, Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null'). cb=gapi.loaded_0:49
(anonymous function)

Comment: How are you launching the app in the browser via the file:// or via the http://localhost.... ?

Comment: The app is launched via file, however the Google Client API loaded refers to the localhost.

Comment: Please serve the file via a localhost server and see what happens.

Comment: @Romin same above issue still persist! Any help?

Comment: I have run out of options and a bit difficult without seeing the actual code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Romin thank you for your support, if you need to see a specific part of the code kindly let me know

Comment: If you can put a basic version of the JavaScript client - I can try to see what could be happening. I will hook it probably to my Endpoints and see if all is well.

Comment: com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.DevApiUtil.stripLeadingSlash(DevApiUtil.java:17) is having a weired url. Try printing wht url it is using

Comment: I hope you have already checked https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#running_and_testing_api_backends_locally

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/`

It seems that the devapiutil takes `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api` as base url without check and it checks what comes after. / character will tell that's your root.

see more:

[Google appEngine: 404 when accesing /_ah/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645741/google-appengine-404-when-accesing-ah-api)